# Populate an observable stream

Tags: angular, rxjs

With Observable, I would like to populate a stream with connected user.

In a book, I read an exemple which very similar to the code below:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject, BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {User} from "./user";
import {IUserService} from "./IUserService";

let initialConnectedUsers: User[] = [];
interface IUsersOperation extends Function {
    (users: User[]): User[];
}

@Injectable()
export class UserService implements IUserService{
    currentUser: Subject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);

    newUser: Subject<User> = new Subject<User>();
    connectedUsers: Observable<User[]>;

    updates: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
    create: Subject<User> = new Subject<User>();

    constructor(){
        this.connectedUsers = this.updates
            .scan((users: User[], operation: IUsersOperation) => {
                    return operation(users);
                },
                initialConnectedUsers)
            .publishReplay(1)
            .refCount();

        this.create.map(function (user: User): IUsersOperation {
            return (users: User[]) => {
                console.log('foo');
                return users.concat(user);
            }
        }).subscribe(this.updates);

        this.newUser.subscribe(this.create);
    }

    public setCurrentUser(newUser: User): void {
        this.currentUser.next(newUser);
        this.newUser.next(newUser);
    }
}

export var userServiceInjectables: Array<any> = [
    UserService
];
```

But in my case the Observable "create" don't use and I don't see the console log.

Comment: What does *"in my case the Observable "create" don't use"* mean?

Comment: You can read here (https://github.com/ng-book/angular2-rxjs-chat/blob/master/app/ts/services/MessagesService.ts) the code what inspired me. In that code the equivalent of connectedUsers is populated with observables create and update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the initialization of application (for exemple: app.component.ts) I write this code:

```
this.userService.connectedUsers.subscribe(() => ({}));
```